# What “firebase init” feature to use for android and iOS projects

Tags: android, ios, firebase, deployment, crashlytics

I want to setup our existing android and iOS projects for firebase test deployment and I don't know which `firebase init` option I should use as none of those option look particular helpful:

```
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
❯◯ Database: Deploy Firebase Realtime Database Rules
 ◯ Firestore: Deploy rules and create indexes for Firestore
 ◯ Functions: Configure and deploy Cloud Functions
 ◯ Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
 ◯ Storage: Deploy Cloud Storage security rules
 ◯ Emulators: Set up local emulators for Firebase features
```

Perviously we used crashlytics to upload and distribute the test applications.

---

**Update 1:** To clarify: I'm working in migrating the `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadDistribution…` task to the new firebase environment.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI is not helpful for configuring Android and iOS mobile clients.  You should follow the instructions for each platform in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).  These instructions will not involve the Firebase CLI in any way.  Each platform has its own way of uploading crashlytics symbols.

Comment: I work on the continues deployment and not the analytics. Having to change code feels kind of wrong for the task at hand.

Comment: I'm sure you can write some script to configure your mobile clients as required by your CI/CD system.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `firebase init`, it serves a different purpose.

You need `firebase login:ci`

you could read more here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli